# Add reference to dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, reference, .net-assembly

I am creating an assembly programaticly and I want to reference to dll that I have on the disk
How to do that with this code.

```
AssemblyName assemblyNameObj = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyNameObj, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
```

Comment: Are you talking about loading the assembly? If so: `Assembly.Load()`

Comment: I am not sure, should I load the assembly that I wont to be added as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Referencing" the assembly is a compile time feature.  Since this is a *dynamically generated* assembly, it doesn't exist at compile time.

You would need to use `Assembly.Load` or similar to load the assembly after you create it, then use Reflection to instantiate the appropriate types within that assembly.